# Trying to create a python script to answer a maths question with n! combinations

Tags: python, math, combinations

I've tried to make a script to answer my math question in python but I'm yet to be successful.

I need to find all the possible arrangements from a string of characters without using them twice. **Example :** I have the letters "a,b,c" and 2 out of the 6 possibilities are "abc" or "bca" but "aab" is not a valid combination.

There are N factorial possibilities thus the list grows really fast, so I thought I'd make a piece of code that spits all the arrangements out. I tried to make one for a 3 letter word by assembling 3 for loops on each other but I don't get all the arrangements and at this point I have no idea what to do and my head is hurting.

I implore you to help me. **Any** suggestions on how to solve it is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `itertools` in python has this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are built-in python libraries [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) which will do this. However because you said you were solving a math problem I will assume you want to do it by yourself, here is a recursion based code to do it:

```
def permutations(prefix, input_str):
    # base case
    if len(input_str) == 1:
        print(f"{prefix}{input_str}")
    else:
        # loop over string to split into groups of two 
        # eg: for "abc" : (a, bc), (b, ac), (c,ab)
        for i in range(len(input_str)):
            permutations(prefix+input_str[i], input_str[:i]+input_str[i+1:])


permutations("", "abc")
```

which gives:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

perm = permutations(['a', 'b', 'c'], 3)
for i in perm:
    print(*i, sep='')
```

Output:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```